# Limit points of sets in co-finite and co-countable topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a (non-empty) set. Let $A$ be any subset of $X$.

Let $\mathscr{T}_f$ denote the co-finite topology on $X$, that is, let
$$
\mathscr{T}_f := \big\{ U \, | \, U \subset X \mbox{ and } X\setminus U \mbox{ is finite } \big\} \bigcup \big\{ \emptyset \big\}. 
$$

And, let $\mathscr{T}_c$ denote the co-countable topology on $X$, that is, let
$$
\mathscr{T}_c := \big\{ U \, |\, U \subset X \mbox{ and } X\setminus U \mbox{ is countable } \big\} \bigcup \big\{ \emptyset \big\}. 
$$

Let $A^d$ denote the derived set of $A$ (i.e. the set of all the limit point of $A$).

Then can we find $A^d$ in the topological space $\left( X, \mathscr{T}_f \right)$? in the topological space $\left( X, \mathscr{T}_c \right)$?

If $A = \emptyset$, then $A^d = \emptyset$ of course in either space.

If $X$ is finite (respectively countable), then $\mathscr{T}_f$ (respectively $\mathscr{T}_c$) is the discrete topology $\mathscr{P}(X)$ on $X$, and in that cases $A^d = \emptyset$ in the topological space $\left( X, \mathscr{T}_f \right)$ (respectively in the topological space $\left( X, \mathscr{T}_c \right)$).

What if $X$ is countable? What is $A^d$ in $\left( X, \mathscr{T}_f \right)$?

What if $X$ is neither finite nor countable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's work with co-finite topology for now.

If $A$ is finite, then taking $U = \{x\}\cup X\setminus A$ we see that $U$ is co-finite, and $A\cap U\subseteq \{x\}$ so that $x$ is not a limit point of $A$. Hence $A^d = \emptyset$.

On the other hand, if $A$ were infinite, then taking any co-finite neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, we see that if it were $(U\setminus \{x\})\cap A = \emptyset$, then $A\subseteq U^c\cup \{x\}$, so since $A$ would be a subset of a finite set, it would itself be finite. This is impossible, so there is $y \in (U\setminus \{x\}) \cap A$. It follows that $x$ is a limit point of $A$, so that $A^d = X$.

So $A^d = \emptyset$ if $A$ is finite and $A^d = X$ if $A$ is infinite.

Now for co-countable topology, the results are completely analogous. In this topology, if $A^d = \emptyset$ if $A$ is countable and $A^d = X$ if $A$ is uncountable.